# Retrieve information from a specific row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a cleaner way to retrieve the info from a specific row (in my case from the last one) other than filtering the necessary row + using iterrows?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_info_1': [11, 12, 13, 14],
                   'some_info_2': [21, 22, 23, 24],
                   'some_info_3': [31, 32, 33, 34]})
    
    # retrieve the last row and apply itterrows
    for index, row in df.iloc[-1:].iterrows():
        # retrieve specific column values of the last row
        last_row_some_info_1 = row["some_info_1"]
        last_row_some_info_2 = row["some_info_2"]
        last_row_some_info_3 = row["some_info_3"]

        print(last_row_some_info_1)
        print(last_row_some_info_2)
        print(last_row_some_info_3)
```

output:

```
14
24
34
```

The solution offered by @adir abargil doesn't seem to be quite efficient if we need multiple column values, since it means that in that case, we would have to retrieve the same row multiple times.

Also, the following approach would not work, as the "test_row" in this case will point to a *dataframe* *containing* the last row but not the row itself.
Therefore the output would not be the same:

```
test_row = df.iloc[-1:]
print(test_row["some_info_1"])
```

output:

```
3    14
Name: some_info_1, dtype: int64
```

Regards,

**UPDATE** 20201118: Added sample input with the expected output
**UPDATE** 20201120: Added a sample of retrieving the value directly from df.iloc[-1:]

Comment: Might I also suggest you this excellent read- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html

Comment: Please post a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
specific =df.iloc[-1]["col_name"]
```

**update** according to comment:

if you want to avoid calling `df.iloc[-1]` many time just save it as variable:

```
row = df.iloc[-1]
specific1 = row['col_1']
specific2 = row['col_2']
```

Comment: Nope; how to retrieve multiple values, without searching for the row multiple times? 
If I want to replicate the behavior I gave in the question using your method, it would be:
`specific1 = df.iloc[-1]["col_name1"]
specific2 = df.iloc[-1]["col_name2"] `; which doesn't seem to be efficient since in that case we'd need to retrieve the last row multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't work either, please see the last update in the question.

Comment: There is a slight diffrence between what you have posted and what i suggested.., i suggested `iloc[-1]`, you posted: `iloc[-1:]`